# Dimension Size to align the same size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, black, dimensions, white

I hope someone in here can help or guide me to understand how this works. I work a lot of black and white aerial photos and they were contracted from a scanned company. They scanned a lot of these old historical photos and they are all in different dimension sizes . They are scanned in .tif files and are in black and white.

For example, if I need to work 4 different aerial photos to do co-registration in order for them to overlap properly. I have 3 of them that are in photos and they are in the same dimension size but one of them is not.

Is there a way for me to get the one to them to align the same  or closer to dimension size with the rest of the other 3 photos ? I don't want to lose some of them.

The reason for this is because if I have different dimensions , it is difficult to line up them correctly. If you have 4 different photos with the same dimensions , it is so much easier this way.

I have Adobe Creative Cloud Photoshop here.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not really sure what you are asking here to be honest, but if you resize an image, will it not change the size of the image? Then you won't be able to align them anyway.

Comment: Different dimensions can man a lot of things. So the images have different number of pixels or?

Comment: Not sure I follow either. It's a fairly easy thing to scale or crop a collection of images so they are all the same width/height/resolution. That *may* or *may not* adversely effect the quality of any single image. It's not possible to be definitive without examining the original images.

Comment: How many pictures do you have? If you have 4 the just crop them to the same size with the cropping tool. If you really have a lot like 100+ then you could use a Automate-Batch Action.

Comment: It seems to me that the size of the image, and the resolution for that matter, are secondary. It is the scale of the things contained in the image which, if not the same, would make lining them up properly very difficult. Were the pictures taken at the same time? from the same elevation? the same camera lens? Did the company that scanned them enlarge or reduce them differently ? If the photographed objects scale is not the same then you will need to unify the scale of the objects photographed by enlarging or reducing the images so their scales match each other.

Comment: @Kyle - yeah that's what I was thinking when commenting, but you expressed it better. The size of the images is really irrelevant, only the scale is what's important. If they're messed up, then the only real option would be to manually rescale. Perhaps if some features appear on two images, one could measure them with the Ruler tool, and adjust the scale of one numerically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Find a common part of the image. Make measures, in my case I've picked the height in pixels. The right dimension image part has 50px height, the wrong one has 70px height.

I just divided the right height by the wrong one then multiplied by 100.
This way I found the right percentage I must reduce the wrong image.
Now I can scale it using that result.

See the image below (I hope I'm clear enough):

[image]